# DispEx Redirecting not working for pdf documents

Tags: pdf

Have some problem with DispEx function. I open .pdf document in client app (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC) using DispEx function, and after closing client app my page should reload (its works for .docx documents), but it does not work. I verify `g_varSkipRefreshOnFocu` var and its value is 0, as MS recommends.

Example:

```
DispEx(dispCtx, evnt, "True", "False",
            "False", "AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments", "1", actXClass, "", "",
            "", "1", "0", "0", "0x7fffffffffffffff");
```